# I open the contact list in android. Upon clicking the user chooses contacts. How is it possible that the view stays there where it was chosen?

Tags: android, android-studio, contacts, android-cursor, onactivityresult

I open the contact list with the callContact method:

```
  public void callContact(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

}
```

Then using two methods, onActivityResult and savePickedContact, I achieved that the user clicks on a name and the number is saved into a list. (It also writes out in a Toast: "You've picked XY").

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult ( int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    savePickedContact(data, this);
                }
                break;
        }
    }


private void savePickedContact(Intent data, MainActivity from) {
    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Cursor contactCur = from.managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    if (contactCur.moveToFirst()) {

/////////////HERE IS THE UGLY IDEA I AM WRITING ABOUT BELOW  /////////////////  /   
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);   //IT WORKS! (?)
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
/////////////////////////////////////// 

        for (int i = 0; i < contactCur.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            String columnName = contactCur.getColumnName(i);
            String value = contactCur.getString(i);
        }
        ContentResolver cr = from.getContentResolver();
        Cursor phonesCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " =?",
                new String[]{contactCur.getString(contactCur.getColumnIndex("_id"))},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
        Boolean hasData = phonesCur.moveToFirst();
        if(hasData) {
            String phoneNumber = phonesCur.getString(phonesCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
            String name = phonesCur.getString(phonesCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            hasData = phonesCur.moveToNext();
            Toast.makeText(this, "You've picked " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            phones.add(phoneNumber);
        }
        phonesCur.close();
    }
```

At the beginning after clicking it went into the activity from which I opened the contact list, but I wanted the user to stay in the contact list, until he clicks on the 'back' button on the phone.

I 'solved' this problem with kind of an ugly idea, in fact after the click I call the contact list once again, as I did in the callContact method. (I marked this part in the code, as you see.) This way the user stays in the contact list at least, but it jumps back to the begininnig. Can anyone know how is it possible that upon clicking we are not going back to the activity and neither are we jumping to the top of the list.

Many thanks in advance.